# How to get the total in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have created simple inventory control form using query.it consists of(product name,price)
after click add button it will append on the table row successfully. my problem is after add price one my one finaly i couldn't calculate the final total.i don't know how to do this. what i tried so far. i wrote it below.can any one go through the code and give the good solution for it.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery Add / Remove Table Rows</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            table{
                width: 100%;
                margin: 20px 0;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            table, th, td{
                border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
            }
            table th, table td{
                padding: 5px;
                text-align: left;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".add-row").click(function(){
                    tot = 0;
                    var ProductName = $("#ProductName").val();
                    var Price = $("#Price").val();
                    var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" + ProductName + "</td><td>" + Price + "</td></tr>";
                    $("table tbody").append(markup);

                        tot += parseFloat(email);


                });
                // Find and remove selected table rows
                $(".delete-row").click(function(){
                    $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
                        if($(this).is(":checked")){
                            $(this).parents("tr").remove();
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="ProductName" placeholder="ProductName">
        <input type="text" id="Price" placeholder="Price">
        <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row">
        <label>Amount </label>
        <input type="text" size="30" height="20" id="tot" placeholder="Total">
    </form>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>ProductName</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="delete-row">Delete Row</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: rectified addition and added code for deletion too !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My possible solution could be creating `addRow`, `deleteRow`, `onRowAdded` and `onRowDeleted` methods to split the code and let every methods to do their parts.

```
function addRow(product) {
    var $tableB = $('table tbody');
    var $row = $("<tr><td class=\"delete-row\"><a href=\"#\">Delete</a></td><td>" + product.name + "</td><td class=\"price\">" + product.price + "</td></tr>");
     $row.data("name", product.name);
     $row.data("price", product.price);
     $row.find('.delete-row').click(function(event) { 
         deleteRow($(event.currentTarget).parent('tr'));
     });
     $tableB.append($row);
     onRowAdded($row);
}
function deleteRow(row) {
    $(row).remove();
    onRowDeleted();
}

function onRowAdded(row) {
    updateTotal();
}

function onRowDeleted(roe) {
    updateTotal();
}
```

Also I will use the `dataset` with help of jQuery with `.data()` method to store the raw values and display my own in the UI.

See the fiddle to better understand my approach.

```js
$(".add-row").click(function() {
  var product = {
    name: $("#ProductName").val(),
    price: $("#Price").val()
  };
  addRow(product);
});

$(".delete-selected-row").click(function() {

  $tableB = $("table tbody");

  $tableB.find('input[name="record"]:checked').parents('tr').each(function(index, elem) {
    deleteRow($(elem));
  });
});

function addRow(product) {
  var $tableB = $('table tbody');
  var $row = $("<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td class=\"delete-row\"><a href=\"#\">Delete</a></td><td>" + product.name + "</td><td class=\"price\">" + product.price + " €</td></tr>");
  $row.data("name", product.name);
  $row.data("price", product.price);
  $row.find('.delete-row').click(function(event) {
    deleteRow($(event.currentTarget).parent('tr'));
  });
  $tableB.append($row);
  onRowAdded($row);
}

function deleteRow(row) {
  $(row).remove();
  onRowRemoved();
}

function updateTotal() {
  var total = $('table tbody tr').toArray().reduce(function(pre, post) {
    return pre + parseFloat($(post).data('price'));
  }, 0);
  $('table tfoot .total').parent('tr').data('total', total);
  $('table tfoot .total').text(total + ' €');
}

function onRowAdded(row) {
  updateTotal();
}

function onRowRemoved(roe) {
  updateTotal();
}

$('.get-data').click(function() {
  console.log(getData());
});

function getData() {
  var data = {};
  data.total = $('table tfoot .total').parent('tr').data('total') || 0;
  
  data.products = $('table tbody tr')
    .toArray() // converts the jQuery node list to an array
    .map((elem) => {
      return {
        name: $(elem).data('name'),
        price: $(elem).data('price'),
      };
    }) // map the array
    ;
    
    return data;
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}

table td.total-title {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="ProductName" placeholder="ProductName">
    <input type="text" id="Price" placeholder="Price">
    <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row">
    <label>Amount </label>
  </form>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Select</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
        <th>Product name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><button type="button" class="delete-selected-row">Delete Row</button></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="total-title">Total:</td>
        <td class="total">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><button type="button" class="delete-selected-row">Delete Row</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
  <button type="button" class="get-data">Get data</button>
  <pre class="output"></pre>
</body>
```

Comment: sir can you explain how to create simple print receipt in above data

Comment: @GowryKanth I don't understand what you are looking for, which data do you want to print and how?

Comment: yes. sir. i just want to print above data product name and prices and final total only sir.

Comment: You can print data everywhere you want. Simply read the `$('table tbody tr').data('name')` for product name, `$('table tbody tr').data('price')` for product price, `$('table tfoot .total').parent('tr').data('total');` for total,

Comment: @GowryKanth just updated the example, now with getData you can retrieve the object like data

Comment: thanks for this sir.can write the full code. it is easy to understand pls sir

Comment: See the example, the `getData` method

Comment: can write the full code sir it is easy for understanding

Comment: Why I have to write the code in comments when it is available in answer? It is formatted an easily readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <body>
    <form>
       <input type="text" id="ProductName" placeholder="ProductName">
       <input type="text" id="Price" placeholder="Price">
       <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row">
       <label>Amount </label>
       <input type="text" size="30" height="20" id="tot" placeholder="Total" readonly>
    </form>
 </body>

 <script>

    $(".add-row").click(function(){ 
       var ProductName = $("#ProductName").val();
       var Price = $("#Price").val();
       var tot = $("#tot").val();
       if(tot == ""){
          tot = 0;
       }
       tot = parseFloat(tot) + parseFloat(Price);

       $("#tot").val(tot);
       var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" + ProductName + "</td><td>" + Price + "</td></tr>";
       $("table tbody").append(markup);
   });

   $(".delete-row").click(function(){
       $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                var total = parseFloat($("#tot").val());
                var newtotal = total - parseFloat($(this).data("price"));
                $("#tot").val(newtotal);
                $(this).parents("tr").remove();
            }
       });
   });

 </script>
```

Comment: Can you highlight which steps you took to solve the problem?

Comment: Sir. when I add the first time price become 0 second time only I add the price only it will display the amount on the textbox. and if i click delete button row will be deleted but the amount didn't reduce.can you solve these two problems

Comment: This will not work for deletion of items

Comment: @GowryKanth I have moved addition code outside else loop, this will solve your first time total showing 0 issue. I have added delete code as well. please check

Answer (score 0):

`var tot = 0;` declared globally

Added for addition of items

```
if(total="")
{
  tot = parseInt(Price);
}else{
  tot += parseInt(Price);
}

$("#tot").val(tot);
```

Added for deletion of items

```
tot -= parseInt($(this).data("price"));
$("#tot").val(tot);
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var  tot = 0;
                $(".add-row").click(function(){
                   
                    var ProductName = $("#ProductName").val();
                    var Price = $("#Price").val();
                    var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record' data-price='"+ Price +"'></td><td>" + ProductName + "</td><td>" + Price + "</td></tr>";         var total = $("#tot").val();
                    if(total="")
                    {
                        tot = parseInt(Price);
                    }else{
                        tot += parseInt(Price);
                    }
                    
                    $("#tot").val(tot);
                    
                    $("table tbody").append(markup);

                });
                // Find and remove selected table rows
                $(".delete-row").click(function(){
                    $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
                        if($(this).is(":checked")){
                         //var total = $("#tot").val();
                         tot -= parseInt($(this).data("price"));
                          $("#tot").val(tot);
                            $(this).parents("tr").remove();
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

```css
  table{
                width: 100%;
                margin: 20px 0;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            table, th, td{
                border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
            }
            table th, table td{
                padding: 5px;
                text-align: left;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery Add / Remove Table Rows</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="ProductName" placeholder="ProductName">
        <input type="text" id="Price" placeholder="Price">
        <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row">
        <label>Amount </label>
        <input type="text" size="30" height="20" id="tot" placeholder="Total">
    </form>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>ProductName</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="delete-row">Delete Row</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Awesome man thanks for you kind help